# When I open PDF with link without www I got redirected to parent folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, pdf, redirect

Basically I got http://avitel-bg.com/xdocs/MCACC.pdf

When I open it i got redirected to parent folder of xdocs (root) and I can't view the file. If I open the link with www ( http://www.avitel-bg.com/xdocs/MCACC.pdf ) I can view the PDF normally.

This is my htaccess:

```
            Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

            RewriteEngine on
            rewritecond %{http_host} ^avitel-bg.com/ [nc]
            rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.avitel-bg.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

            # BEGIN products Rewrite
            RewriteRule ^(kadmin)(/.*)?$ - [L]
            RewriteRule ^(kadmin2)(/.*)?$ - [L]
            RewriteRule ^(polycomp)(/.*)?$ - [L]
            RewriteRule ^(.*)-cat([0-9]+) categories.php?cid=$2 [L,NC]
            RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ products.php?pid=$1 [L]


            # END products Rewrite
            <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
            ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
            </IfModule>

            <IfModule mod_geoip.c>
            GeoIPEnable On
            SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE (US|CH) DenyCountry
            </IfModule> 

            <IfModule mod_expires.c>
            ExpiresActive on
            ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
            ExpiresByType image/x-ico "access plus 1 year"
            ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 14 days"
            ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 14 days"
            ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 14 days"
            ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 14 days"
            ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 14 days"
            </IfModule>

            <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/xml text/css text/plain
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE img/svg+xml application/xhtml+xml application/xml
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rdf+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf application/x-font-otf
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/truetype font/opentype
            </IfModule>

            <ifModule mod_gzip.c>
            mod_gzip_on Yes
            mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
            mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
            mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
            mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
            mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
            mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
            mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
            </ifModule>

            <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
              Options +FollowSymlinks
              RewriteEngine On
              RewriteBase /
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
                RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            </IfModule>
```

Comment: `[r=301,nc]` there's no `L`(ast), so rewrites can continue processing and one of your later rules is probably UNDOING what the example.com->www.example.com rule did.

Comment: It doesnt work when I delete the other rules. I just dont get how I get redirected when I open
 http:// avitel-bg.com/ **xdocs** /MCACC.pdf to http:// www .avitel-bg.com/MCACC.pdf . It removes the folder somehow..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your redirect destination as it redirects all non-www requests to root

If you want to redirect non-www to requests to subfolder, change your last rule to this :

```
RewriteEngine on
            rewritecond %{http_host} ^avitel-bg.com [nc]
            rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.avitel-bg.com/xdocs/$1 [r=301,nc,l]
```